# In Oracle Spatial (SDO), is there a way to get the centroid point of a polygon that is contained by the surface of the polygon?

Tags: oracle, gis, geospatial, oracle-spatial

I need to find the centroid of a polygon in Oracle Spatial that exists inside of the polygon itself.  I cannot use the sdo_geom.sdo_centroid method because this returns a point outside of the shape if the shape resembles a horseshoe.

I found sdo_geom.sdo_pointonsurface method, but it returns a point that is *just* on the edge of the polygon.  While this mathematically works, it is not safe in our environment because all polygons share a boundary with other polygons and sometimes there is a slight overlap in the data.  This overlap cannot include the calculated point.

Is there another approach to finding this point without writing custom code?  I'm not opposed to writing custom code for this, but I would like to use something pre-built if it already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Greener has a package for a "para-centroid": `codesys.geom.sdo_centroid`.

You can download it, but I don't know if there is any sort of licensing that is attached to the source.

Here are links:

- [Oracle Locator vs Oracle Spatial: A Reflection on Oracle Licensing of the SDO_GEOM Package](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/55/oracle-locator-vs-enterprise-licensing-the-sdogeom-package)
- [Shapefile Exporter package for Oracle 10gR2](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/source_code)

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I was looking for.  I had come across the site but couldn't find where he actually put the source code.  Thanks again!